# HP DL380 G7 Server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

Can I use LRDIMM (HP) in a `HP DL380 G7 server` ?

It currently has 2 `2GB RDIMM` (*10600R*), which I will remove and would like to add 4 x `4GB LRDIMM` (*10600R*).

Comment: Questions on SU are expected to [show some research effort](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) on your part and should be included in your question please.

Comment: use the HP memory configuration tool http://h22195.www2.hp.com/DDR4memoryconfig/Home/Legal

Answer (score 0):

According to HP's website the HP DL380 G7 can accept "DDR3 Registered (RDIMM) and Unbuffered (UDIMM)" RAM sticks. My guess is that LRDIMM will not work, servers can be quite picky about RAM and LRDIMM is, I believe quad ranked. HP Gen8 servers can definitely support LRDIMM.